# Why do I keep getting the "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I have implemented the following test class:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;  
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@DataMongoTest(properties = {"spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @DisplayName("Test display name")
    @Test
    public void test(@Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        // given
        DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("key", "value")
            .get();

        // when
        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

        // then
        Assertions.assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "collection")).extracting("key")
                .containsOnly("value");
    }

}
```

This is exactly the same as in Springs documentation, however when I run the test I keep getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

and

```
2022-01-04 10:35:02 UTC | WARN  | AnnotationConfigApplicationContext | Exception encountered during context 
initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. 
Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
```

What am I doing wrong? What I'm trying to do is to test with an embedded, in-memory MongoDB.

Update:

This is my project structure:

```
▼ src
    ▼ main
        ▼ java
            ▼ youben
                  YouBenApplication (Spring Boot Runnable Class)
    ▼ test
        ▼ java
            ▼ youben
                  MyIntegrationTest (this is the test class)
```

Here is my the runnable class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YouBenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YouBenApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have used this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb).

The following annotations seem to be correct

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

However as [spring doc for embedded mongo db](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.nosql.mongodb.embedded) advices you should define the embedded mongo db version that should be used.

So you should configure those previous annotations as

```
@DataMongoTest(properties = {"spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

if for example you need the version `4.0.2`
\

**Edit**:

For `@ExtendWith` to work you have to also have a spring boot application configured in your `main` directory. Using only `test` directory alone is not sufficient.

So make sure that you have in `src/main/java/yourpackage` something like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceLauncher.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Important!** Tests should also be in the same `mypackage` directory example `src/test/java/yourpackage`

Comment: You are correct, that's exactly the example I've used. I've tried to replace the annotation but now I get the following errors:

`java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods` and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Comment: Okay, I've configured the annotation with the version as you've suggested, however it still gives the error: `Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

As far as I know that has something to do with the `@Autowired` annotation, but I just don't exactly what the error is.

Comment: What I've posted is the complete code.

Comment: Okay I do have the spring boot application configured in my `main` directory, however the test class is in the `test` folder and not in the `main` folder. So maybe that's the issue.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` should correctly be in `main/java/yourpackage` and the test should be in `test/java/yourpackage` . It is also neccessary that you have defined `yourpackage`

Comment: Done exactly what you said, still getting same error.

Comment: Okay I've updated the post with the error and the new things.

Comment: @Ben I beleive that somewhere you have the property `spring.data.mongodb.uri:....` and this is the one causing this issue

Comment: Oh yeah, I have it in my application.properties file. But I need that for the actual code, meaning the `main` part of the project, and but at the same time the test side should not use that, it should just use an in-memory mongoDB. Is that not possible?

Comment: Okay I've introduced a new file: ´application-test.properties´ containing the following property: ´spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017´. In the test class I've set an active profile ´@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})´ now it gives the error: ´Database name must not be empty!´

Comment: @Ben check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html the properties that start with `spring.data.mongodb` and make the according changes

Comment: Okay I needed `spring.data.mongo.database=<my db name>` . Works now, thank you very much, you've helped me so much. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that in the tutorial they have provided dependecy like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

but you actually need to define version of **de.flapdoodle.embed**.

So the fix was simply to add version of the dependency to the pom.xml file like this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
     <version>4.7.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```